# How to save multiple versions of a file on GitHub

Tags: github

I'm fairly new to programming and thought I'd try out version control. I created a GitHub account to help me track my journey of creating my first webpage.

I want to upload updated versions of my code as I go along (e.g. Stage1, then perhaps when I progress a little further Stage2, then Stage 3 etc). This would essentially be the same file of code but each time it will be added to/ edited slightly.

Could someone advise me as to how to do this?
Thank you! :)

Comment: I think your question is too broad, because you're basically asking "how does git work?". I advice you look up some of the existing Git tutorials (there are some that get right to the important stuff and explain it in easy terms). But as a first pointer: what you're trying to do is exactly the purpose of version control. You push ("upload") updated versions of your files to the repository and can go back at any time. Hint: try to push a lot of small changes. Don't just push "versions" with tons of changes every now and then.

Comment: A lot of my former fellow students really liked [this "no deep shit" guide to git](https://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/). Or maybe you're more into [the official tutorial](https://git-scm.com/docs/gittutorial). Or find others. There are plenty. And if I may give one more piece of advice: I recommend working with git from the command line instead of using GUI tools. It will benefit you in the long term.

Comment: Thank you! I'll definitely check out that guide, and look into using GIT from the command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Every commit** you push to your repository is stored and then you can access every version that you have committed afterward.

Just go into your repo, click at your commits tab:
[Commits Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uf6mZ.png)

Then you can access the version by clicking the commit hash you desire to browse:
[Commit hash abbreviated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0TxT.png)

After this, you just click in browse files.

If you want to use in your computer **another version**, you just have to `git checkout 'commit hash'` inside your folder at sync with your git repo.

Comment: Thank you that makes a lot of sense!